# What is meant by relative frequency in calibration curves

Tags: probability, classification, calibration

After reading docs on scikit learn on the [probability calibration](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) there's couple concerns that bug me. I don’t really understand how the curve values are calculated (y-axis) namely the frequencies. Are the predictions first split to N bins (based on peedictions) and then the frequency of positive labels related to those predictions plotted? (Y axis)?
Also if the model just rounds its predictions it would just be 100% accurate line? With 2 bins?

Comment: The title asks about "relative frequency" in calibration curves, but you don't mention this nor is it defined anywhere in the link. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are few proposed measures of calibration, but the most widely circulated is the so called Hosmer-Lemeshow statistic. At a 10,000 view, this test works by binning a risk model into deciles, and then calculating the expected event frequency versus the observed event frequency within each decile. The "x"-axis here is the average predicted risk for each of the 10 deciles, and the "y"-axis is the corresponding proportion of events in each decile. Ideally the curve lies on a straight line. And the deviations follow a binomial probability model.

The choice of 10 bins is due to Hosmer and Lemeshow, but can easily be taken to be more, and can be chosen with non-empirical (i.e. quantile) thresholds. Then you get into some of the known measures of risk stratification tables. However all of these are problematic.

To me, a more intuitive measure of calibration is the Brier score. This is just the MSE. Brier pointed out this is a valid and useful measure even when the data are binary, and it favors closer predictions on the absolute risk scale which is favorable for many reasons!

I started the Wiki for the HL test long ago, yet it appears to be in severe disarray. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosmer%E2%80%93Lemeshow_test